# В чем различия между INNER JOIN и OUTER JOIN?

Tags: sql, join

- В чем разница между `INNER JOIN` и `OUTER JOIN`?
- Что означают `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` и `FULL JOIN`?

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[Difference between INNER and OUTER joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/)» [@cdv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3836/cdv).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Предположим, вы хотите выполнить соединение по столбцам без дубликатов, что встречается довольно часто:

- Внутреннее соединение A и B: A пересекает B, т.е. внутренняя часть пересечения [диаграммы Венна](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram).
- Внешнее соединение A и B: A соединяется с B, т.е. внешняя часть соединения на диаграмме Венна.

**Примеры**

Предположим, у вас есть две таблицы. Каждая состоит из одного столбца, со следующими значениями:

```
A    B
-    -
1    3
2    4
3    5
4    6
```

Обратите внимание, что (1,2) уникальны для A, (3,4) – общие элементы, а (5,6) уникальны для B.

**Внутреннее соединение**

Внутреннее соединение, использующее один из эквивалентных запросов, дает пересечение двух таблиц, то есть две строки, общие для каждой из них.

```
select * from a INNER JOIN b on a.a = b.b;
select a.*, b.*  from a, b where a.a = b.b;

a | b
--+--
3 | 3
4 | 4
```

**Левое внешнее соединение**

Результат левого внешнего соединения – все строки таблицы A плюс все строки таблицы B, имеющие совпадение со строками таблицы А.

```
select * from a LEFT OUTER JOIN b on a.a = b.b;
select a.*, b.*  from a, b where a.a = b.b(+);

a |  b
--+-----
1 | null
2 | null
3 |    3
4 |    4
```

**Правое внешнее соединение**

Результат правого внешнего соединения – все строки таблицы В плюс все строки таблицы А, имеющие совпадение со строками таблицы В.

```
select * from a RIGHT OUTER JOIN b on a.a = b.b;
select a.*,b.*  from a,b where a.a(+) = b.b;

a    |  b
-----+----
3    |  3
4    |  4
null |  5
null |  6
```

**Полное внешнее соединение**

Результат полного внешнего соединения – соединение таблиц A и B, т.е. все строки A и все строки B. Если какой-либо элемент таблицы A не имеет соответствия в таблице B, эта часть B пуста, и наоборот.

```
select * from a FULL OUTER JOIN b on a.a = b.b;

 a   |  b
-----+-----
   1 | null
   2 | null
   3 |    3
   4 |    4
null |    6
null |    5
```

<sub>Перевод ответа «[Difference between INNER and OUTER joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38578/564240)» [@Mark Harrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116/mark-harrison).</sub>

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` это то же самое что и `LEFT JOIN` ? По данным примерам это так. Но так ли это на самом деле в ответе не отражено.

Comment: @jekaby да, это так. Левое и правое соединения и так являются внешними (см. [outer join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_join)).

Comment: От души, как боженька объяснил :)

Answer (score 45):

Также вы можете воспользоваться данной схемой для понимания соединения таблиц:

[image: SQL Join]

<sub>Перевод ответа [«Difference between INNER and OUTER joins»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598900/2907755) [@Teoman Shipahi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/929902/teoman-shipahi)</sub>

Comment: Эм.. Я что-то не понимаю, или в чём гениальность идеи делать join, а потом выкидывать все данные из другой таблицы?

Comment: @Qwertiy убирается пересечение таблиц, тут же все наглядно видно.

Comment: @Qwertiy вы про какой из рисунков?

Comment: @D-side, да я в общем-то понял. Хотя такие ситуации редко возникают. Я про `where a.key is null` и два аналогичных.

Comment: @Qwertiy в контексте вопросно-ответного сайта вроде SO так, скажем, можно искать *вопросы без ответов*: соединить вопросы с ответами и отфильтровать только те, у которых совпадений с ответами не оказалось. Случаи не так уж редки.

Comment: Это даже не перевод.

Comment: @Qwertiy Если рассмотреть вариант с left join, то такой запрос нужен когда необходимо найти в таблице А записи у которых каким-то образом заполнено поле key (не null) но отсутствует соответствующая запись в таблице B.

Comment: @ApInvent, да. Я уже понял давно.

Answer (score 2):

INNER-внутреннее соединение (пересечение множеств)-выделяет общее из множеств

LEFT JOIN-левое внешнее соединение-берет все что слева и все то справа, для которого есть соответствие в левом множестве

Answer (score 1):

Что означают, какие различия, а также -- почему такие названия, для всех видов соединения таблиц, наглядно видно на следующем графике:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- `[INNER] JOIN` - внутреннее
- `(LEFT|RIGHT) [OUTER] JOIN` - внешнее, или справа, или слева
- `FULL [OUTER] JOIN` - внешнее, справа и слева, т.е. полнное

Answer (score 1):

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| INNER | JOIN | Возвращает записи которые имеют соответствие в обеих таблицах |
| OUTER | LEFT JOIN | Возвращает все записи из левой таблицы + записи которые имеют соответствие из правой |
| OUTER | RIGHT JOIN | Возвращает все записи из правой таблицы + записи которые имеют соответствие из левой |
| OUTER | FULL JOIN | Возвращает все записи из обеих таблиц |