# Помогите составить SQL-запрос(Не совсем разобрался с JOIN-ами)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Дано 2 таблицы `mailing` и `users`. Мне нужно выбрать следующие данные:

Выбрать список `login` с таблицы `users`, где:

```
(users.id=mailing.uid1, если mailing.uid2 = переменной $N) или (users.id=mailing.uid2, если mailing.uid1 = перемнной $N).
```

[image: Таблица mailing]
(mailing)

[image: Таблица users]
(users)

Comment: Для того, чтобы более детально разобраться с JOIN советую прочесть данную тему: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512193

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно надо в вашем текстовом описании заменить 'если' на and потому что это можно прочитать как 'И'. А так же заменить 'ИЛИ' на 'OR'. Вот и получилось условие :)

```
select *
  from mailing
  join users
    on    (users.id=mailing.uid1 and mailing.uid2 = $N)
       OR (users.id=mailing.uid2 and mailing.uid1 = $N)
```