# Запрос на поиск по ключевому слову из двух таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Всем привет. Есть рабочий запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `realty_kvartiru` 
WHERE (dopolnitelnaya_infa LIKE 'Ленина' 
       OR ulitsa LIKE 'Ленина' 
       OR orientir LIKE 'Ленина')
```

который ищет по ключевому слову в одной таблице `realty_kvartiru` по трем столбцам, как можно его модернизировать, чтоб он искал еще по четвертому полю `agenstvo_title` из второй таблицы `phones`?

таблицы имеют следующую структуру :

**realty_kvartiru**: `id`, `user_id`, `tip`, `tsena`, `rayon_id`, `ulitsa`, `orientir`, `etaj`, `e‌​tajnost`, `kolichestvo‌​_komnat`, `nomer_doma`‌​, `nomer_kvartiru`, `sos‌​toyanie_tip`, `shema_t‌​ip`, `balcon_tip`, `sanu‌​zel_tip`, `istochnik_i‌​d`, `material_tip`, `jul‌​aya_plowad`, `obwaya_p‌​lowad`, `kuhnya_plowad‌​`, `dopolnitelnaya_inf‌​a`, `fio`, `nuzno_prodat‌​`, `is_deleted`, `create‌​d_at`, `updated_at`, `is‌​_imported`, `in_blackl‌​ist`, `in_deleted_list‌​`, `deleted_at`, `secret‌​ary_id`, `call_status`‌, ​`commentary`, `own_typ‌​e`, `is_exclusive`, `lin‌​k`, `deleted_by`, `must_‌​called`, `wanted_to_re‌​move`, `notebook_comme‌​nt`, `agents_realty`

**phones**: `id`, `phone`, `is_posrednik`, `agenstvo_title`

Comment: Выложите структуру таблиц realty_kvartiru и phones.

Comment: видимо что то типа `select * from realty_kvartiru ... OR (id_записи_или_телефон_смотря_какая_у_вас_структура) in(select что-то from phones where agenstvo_title like 'xxx')`

Comment: realty_kvartiru: `id``user_id``tip``tsena``rayon_id``ulitsa``orientir``etaj``etajnost``kolichestvo_komnat``nomer_doma``nomer_kvartiru``sostoyanie_tip``shema_tip``balcon_tip``sanuzel_tip``istochnik_id``material_tip``julaya_plowad``obwaya_plowad``kuhnya_plowad``dopolnitelnaya_infa``fio``nuzno_prodat``is_deleted``created_at``updated_at``is_imported``in_blacklist``in_deleted_list``deleted_at``secretary_id``call_status``commentary``own_type``is_exclusive``link``deleted_by``must_called``wanted_to_remove``notebook_comment``agents_realty`

phones: `id``phone``is_posrednik``agenstvo_title`

Comment: @ultimatum лучше внесите правку в вопрос

Comment: @Denis как именно поправить?

Comment: @ultimatum кнопкой "править")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если эти 2 таблицы можно связать по `id`, то можно:

```
SELECT *
FROM realty_kvartiru r LEFT JOIN phones p ON r.id = p.id
WHERE dopolnitelnaya_infa LIKE 'Ленина' 
       OR ulitsa LIKE 'Ленина' 
       OR orientir LIKE 'Ленина'
       OR agenstvo_title LIKE 'Ленина'
```

Comment: Запрос срабатывает и ошибок не выдает, ищет "Ленина "  в realty_kvartiru, но не находит "Шерлок" в phones -> SELECT *
FROM realty_kvartiru r LEFT JOIN phones p ON r.id = p.id
WHERE dopolnitelnaya_infa LIKE 'Шерлок' 
       OR ulitsa LIKE 'Шерлок' 
       OR orientir LIKE 'Шерлок'
       OR agenstvo_title LIKE 'Шерлок'
P.S.- записи с "Шерлок" в agenstvo_title есть.

Comment: @ultimatum Тут вопрос в соединении таблиц, скорее всего. Так как используется `left join`, то не все элементы из таблицы `phones` могут соединиться с `realty_kvartiru`. Проверьте, есть ли id из строки с Шерлоком в таблице `realty_kvartiru`, и попробуйте для наглядности вывести запрос select, закомментировав условия `where`

Comment: подскажите пож в каком столбце проверить? Должны совпадать id(realty_kvartiru)=id(phones)?

Comment: Если у вас слово "Шерлок" находится в таблице в словосочетании например "Шерлок Холмс"  используйте поиск аля  LIKE '%Шерлок%'
что бы найти любые совпадения независимо оттого где находится искомое слово в строке

Comment: @ Broouzer King 92450
095***5414
1
Шерлок

Comment: @ultimatum предыдущий комментатор правильно сказал. Используйте '%Шерлок%', ибо 'Шерлок' - точное соответствие, как равенство. [Подробнее про LIKE](http://www.firststeps.ru/sql/oracle/r.php?15).

Comment: @Denis в таком исполнении тоже не находит -> SELECT * FROM realty_kvartiru r LEFT JOIN phones p ON r.id = p.id WHERE dopolnitelnaya_infa LIKE '%Шерлок%' OR ulitsa LIKE '%Шерлок%' OR orientir LIKE '%Шерлок%' OR agenstvo_title LIKE '%Шерлок%'

Comment: @Denis а если поменять таблицы местами -> SELECT * FROM phones r LEFT JOIN realty_kvartiru p ON r.id = p.id WHERE dopolnitelnaya_infa LIKE '%Ленина%' OR ulitsa LIKE '%Ленина%' OR orientir LIKE '%Ленина%' OR agenstvo_title LIKE '%Ленина%' "Шерлок " находит, а "Ленина " находит только 2 строки из 100

Comment: @ultimatum вы проверили `id` в обоих таблицах, где есть "Шерлок"? Попробуйте `full join` тогда, посмотрите на несоединённые строки

Comment: $Denis full join выдает ошибку запроса и соответственно не работает

Comment: @ultimatum вы задали просто `select ... from ...` без `where`? Вам же сказали - у вас часть строк может не соединяться из-за того, что в таблице `phones` часть значений `id` отсутствуют в 1 таблице, предположительно как раз отсутствуют те `id`, под которыми есть "Шерлок". Почитайте сначала [про `JOIN`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512193/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-inner-join-%D0%B8-outer-join/512206#512206), либо составьте тестовую таблицу на http://sqlfiddle.com с необходимыми столбцами, убрав все лишние.

Comment: @Denis ок спасибо, я позже отпишусь по результатам

Comment: @Denis спасибо за помощь! разобрался - проблема таки была из-за id

Comment: @ultimatum всегда пожалуйста)

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать оператор UNION
[http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp](http://%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%20UNION)

Comment: В таком формате выдает ошибку запроса и соответственно не работает -> SELECT * FROM `realty_kvartiru` 
WHERE (dopolnitelnaya_infa LIKE 'Ленина' 
       OR ulitsa LIKE 'Ленина' 
       OR orientir LIKE 'Ленина') 
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT * FROM phones WHERE agenstvo_title LIKE 'Ленина'

Comment: @ultimatum конечно ошибку выдаст, потому что количество столбцов в таблицах абсолютно разное.