# Выборка из Many-to-many таблиц по заданному ID

Tags: mysql, sql

**Таблицы:** Животные, Клетки, Смотрители.

**Цель:** по заданному `animalsID` получить все значения из каждой таблицы. Вроде бы написал, возможно неоптимальный, работает.

НО, у `Animal` может отсутствовать смотритель, и тогда мы просто получим `NULL`.

**Вопрос:** как при отсутствии чего-либо получить хотя бы остальные данные?

```
CREATE TABLE `animal` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `animalClass` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `age` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_animal PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `keeper` (
  `keeperID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `surname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_keeper PRIMARY KEY (keeperID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `keeper_animals` (
  `animalID` INT (11) NOT NULL,
  `keeperID` INT (11) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (animalID) REFERENCES animal(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (keeperID) REFERENCES keeper(keeperID),
  UNIQUE (animalID, keeperID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `cage` (
  `cageID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `number` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_cage PRIMARY KEY (cageID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `cage_animals` (
  `animalID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `cageID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (animalID) REFERENCES animal (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (cageID) REFERENCES cage(cageID),
  UNIQUE (animalID, cageID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Сам запрос (быть может его не так пишут?):

```
SELECT 
  animal.id, animal.name, animal.animalClass, animal.age, 
  keeper.keeperID, keeper.name, keeper.surname, 
  cage.cageID, cage.number
FROM animal
  INNER JOIN keeper_animals ON animal.id = keeper_animals.animalID
  INNER JOIN keeper ON keeper_animals.keeperID = keeper.keeperID
  INNER JOIN cage_animals ON animal.id = cage_animals.animalID
  INNER JOIN cage ON cage_animals.cageID = cage.cageID
  WHERE id = "Необходимый ID";
```

Comment: WHERE animal.id = 4;
Вроде бы в этом проблема.

Comment: Дописал, но нет, к сожалению) Если вместо 4, к примеру, поставлю 88,  - `animal` у которого нет смотрителя, то получу все поля `null`.

Comment: посмотрите вот этот [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512206/179270) очень наглядно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Внешнее соединение LEFT JOIN означает, что помимо строк, для которых выполняется условие предиката, в результирующий набор попадут все остальные строки из первой таблицы (левой). При этом отсутствующие значения столбцов из правой таблицы будут заменены NULL-значениями.

[sql-tutorial](http://sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html)

Так что

```
 INNER JOIN keeper_animals ON animal.id = keeper_animals.animalID
 INNER JOIN keeper ON keeper_animals.keeperID = keeper.keeperID
```

заменяем на

```
 LEFT JOIN keeper_animals ON animal.id = keeper_animals.animalID
 LEFT JOIN keeper ON keeper_animals.keeperID = keeper.keeperID
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать)