# Как получить посты, у которых нет категорий?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть посты (таблица posts). К постам можно добавлять категории - связь многие ко многим.

Сейчас я могу выводить посты конкретных категорий:

```
Post.all.where(posts_and_categories: { category_id: [2, 4] }).joins(:posts_and_categories)
```

Но как сделать так, чтобы я мог вывести посты, у которых нет категорий?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## В Rails 5 всё круто!

Rails 5 ввёл **левые соединения** (`LEFT JOIN`, [тут объясняется, что это за зверь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/512193/181100)), так что это делается без каких-либо копаний под капотом, средствами рельс:

- взять посты
- лево-соединить с их посто-категориями
- выбрать посты, у которых вместо посто-категории оказались `NULL`ы

  - достаточно проверить, что в `post_id` значение `NULL`, т. к. это ключ ассоциации, он попадает в  предикат соединения, а `NULL` не равен `NULL` *никогда*, поэтому под условие попадут только строчки, для которых посто-категории не нашлось

```
Post.left_joins(:posts_and_categories)
    .merge(PostsAndCatrgory.where(post_id: nil))
```

---

## А вот в версиях постарше...

А ранее я б предложил (да и [предлагал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30538422/2076787)) воспользоваться SQL'ным `NOT EXISTS`:

```
Post.where(
  "NOT EXISTS (?)",
  PostsAndCategory.where("posts_and_categories.post_id = post.id")
)
```

...а можно избавиться от кусочков SQL, взяв Arel (конструктор запросов ActiveRecord уже построен на нём, так что устанавливать дополнительно ничего не нужно):

```
Post.where(
  PostsAndCategory.where(
    post_id: Post.arel_table[:id]
  )
  .exists
  .not
)
```

---

Второе решение выглядит даже прозрачнее, в нём прямее сказано, что ищется. Разве что скорость работы стоит проверить. Но там не используются данные об ассоциациях, что минус.