# Sql joins in linq

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Есть замечательная схема SQL Joins, которая иллюстрирует различные типы соединений в SQL:

- [В чем различия между INNER JOIN и OUTER JOIN?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/512193/213987)
- [What is the difference between “INNER JOIN” and “OUTER JOIN”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38549/5752652)

[image: SQL Join]

А есть ли подобная схема для построения аналогичных запросов, но не в SQL, а для linq?

Comment: а какая разница, там все те же `join()`, `leftJoin()` вроде?

Comment: Вас интересует именно код запросов или что? Это смотрели: https://habr.com/sandbox/39626/ ?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да, есть такое в закладках, как и скажем, [такое](https://blog.rc21net.ru/join-%D0%B2-linq/). Но как-то не наглядно что ли в linq... sql-ная табличка в голове сидит, а когда начинаешь писать left join через group by - сходу и не вспомнишь, приходится в шпаргалки лезть.

Comment: @AK, как по мне, в LINQ куча этих всевозможных джойнов не нужна, если у вас связь один к одному - просто имейте ссылку на связанный объект, если один ко многим - коллекцию ссылок. В EF навигационные свойства тоже никто не отменял.

Comment: Погуглил, найти подобную картинку для LINQ не удалось. Значит - нужно её сделать! Кто первый успеет - плюсиков огребёт.