# Как сделать выборку по двум связанным таблицам?

Tags: mysql, sql

Надо добавить `first_name, last_name, department_id, department_name`.

**Проблема в том что не знаю, как добавить `department_name`.**

Вот первую часть пишу `select first_name, last_name, department_id from employees`.

**А как добавить `department_name`, если находится в другой таблице 'Departments'?**

Внизу можете увидеть, что `first_name, last_name, department_id` находится в таблице 'Employees'.

```
select first_name, last_name, department_id from employees where department_name not exists (select department_name from departments)  order by employee_id
```

Попробовал так , но не работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитайте про INNER JOIN, а потом поищите свой запрос на [картинке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/512193/213987): where not exist прекрасно заменяется на JOIN с проверкой where key is null

Comment: @AK если ключ пуст, то и джойнить нечего

Comment: спасибо вам . )

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать несколько вариантов для решения данной задачи: сделать выборку из двух таблиц сразу, использовать соединения таблиц, использовать подзапрос.

Для целей как ваша обычно применяют левое соединение `LEFT JOIN`

```
 SELECT first_name, last_name, department_id, department_name
 FROM Employees AS e
 LEFT JOIN Departments AS d ON (e.department_id = d.id)
```

В случае, если `department_id` будет равен `null` (или будет отсутсвовать соответствующая запись присоединяемой таблицы), то все равно будет возвращен полный набор данных исходной таблицы `employees`.

В случае, когда нужно обеспечить соединение (пересечение таблиц) для существующих записей используют внутренее  соединение `INNER JOIN`. Если условие соединения не выполняется, то строка исключается из результирующего набора. Аналогичное поведение будет при выборке из двух таблиц сразу:

```
 SELECT ...
 FROM Employees AS e, Departments as d
 WHERE e.department_id = d.id
```

то есть строится произведение таблиц, и фильтруются нужные записи.

Третий вариант - использовать подзапрос:

```
SELECT  first_name
    ,(
        SELECT d.name 
        FROM departments as d 
        WHERE d.id = e.department_id
    ) as dep_name
FROM Employees as e
```

Comment: спасибо вам  . )