# PHP Выборка из двух таблиц

Tags: php, sql

Столкнулся с таким вопросом: есть 2 таблицы - accounts и payment_transactions. 
В таблице accounts находятся пользователи (id, баланс и тд..)
В payment_transactions записано, когда пользователи пополняли баланс (id, дата, и тд).

Нужно выбрать всех пользователей, которые не платили 3 или более месяца.

Делаю выборку, но в ответ пустой, подскажите, что я делаю не так?

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM accounts INNER JOIN payment_transactions on accounts.id=payment_transactions.payment_enter_date");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['id'] . "</br>";
```

Comment: `on accounts.id=payment_transactions.payment_enter_date` Вот какой смысл сравнивать идентификатор с датой, а?

Comment: @Akina я плохо понимаю вхождение по таблицам(

Comment: @MaxEvans → [В чем различия между INNER JOIN и OUTER JOIN?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512193/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-inner-join-%D0%B8-outer-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM accounts t1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT t2.account_id
            FROM payment_transactions t2
            GROUP BY t2.account_id
            HAVING MAX(t2.payment_enter_date) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH ) t3
     ON t1.id = t3.account_id
WHERE t3.account_id IS NULL
```