# LEFT JOIN, как правильно составить запрос

Tags: sql

Подскажите плиз, есть запрос который вытягивает все нужные мне `product_id`:

```sql
SELECT product_id
FROM oc_product_attribute
WHERE
    text IN (".$get_material_item.")
    AND product_id IN (
        SELECT product_id
        FROM oc_product_attribute
        WHERE text IN (".$get_ves_item.")
    )
GROUP BY product_id
```

Нужно с другой таблицы `'product'` получить `'price'` и `'image'`, а с другой таблицы `'product_description'` получить `'name'`. Тут нужен `Left Join`? Помогите, пожалуйста составить правильно запрос

Comment: в чем разница в соединения, вы можете посмотреть вот в этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/512193/179270), теперь по самому вопросу: `join products p on oc_product_attribute.product_id = p.id` после этого в `select` указываете необходимые поля из таблицы `products`, аналогично поступаете для второй таблицы.

Comment: для лучшего понимания языка запросов sql рекомендую вот этот сайт [sql-tutorial](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/content.html), в свое время мне очень помогло

Answer (score 1):

Так как вы не предоставили информации о названиях полей с идентификатором продукта в таблицах `product` и `product_description`, предположу, что существует поле `product.id` и `product_description.product_id`.

По поводу `Left Join` - важно понимать, что `Left` и `Right` лишь определяют условную сторону, с которой находится целевая таблица при объединении и практически любое соединение можно написать как в левую сторону, так и в правую. Вам нужно об этом почитать подробнее - концепция совсем не сложная. В комментариях дали пару неплохих ссылок [[1]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/512193/179270) [[2]](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/content.html)

Приняв указанные выше допущения, результирующий запрос может выглядеть следующим образом:

```sql
SELECT
    oca.product_id,
    pr.price,
    pr.image,
    pd.name
FROM
    oc_product_attribute AS oca
    LEFT JOIN 
    product AS pr ON pr.id = oca.product_id
    LEFT JOIN
    product_description AS pd ON pd.product_id = oca.product_id
WHERE
    text IN (".$get_material_item.")
    AND oca.product_id IN (
        SELECT oca2.product_id
        FROM oc_product_attribute AS oca2
        WHERE text IN (".$get_ves_item.")
    )
GROUP BY
    oca.product_id
```

Обращу внимание, что при повторном указании таблицы в секции `FROM` в подзапросе, важно разделить вызовы таблиц через алиасы (псевдонимы). В частности, обратите внимание, что таблица `oc_product_attribute` имеет алиасы `oca` и `oca2`. В противном случае вы можете получить некорректную обработку подзапроса (в частности может случится так, что курсоры базы данных в основном запросе и подзапросе будут всегда работать синхронно и, как следствие, вы получите один и тот же `product_id` в обоих запросах)

Comment: Спасибо, единственное что нужно заменить ```product AS pr ON pr.id = oca.product_id``` на ```product AS pr ON pr.product_id = oca.product_id```,
Перенес скрипт в базу, что бы попробавть, поставил вместо переменных значения, и все заработало, переношу в php, и не работает...

Comment: сильно зависит от диалекта sql, используемого в базе. Возможно нужно убрать операторы объявления алиасов `AS` у таблиц (например в Oracle такое бывает). Какую базу и клиент используете?

Comment: использую mysql и pma

Comment: Я все таки надеялся на ms sql или oracle. С mysql не работал

Comment: Ну дело то в том что, скрипт в pma работает, а вот если его перенести в php он не хочет работать...

Comment: выдает bool(false) вот код https://3v4l.org/bRAXC